# Setting the page number in the top of the page

Tags: header-footer

I want to set the page numbering in the top of the page. I used `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` but two problems appeared. The first problem is that the first page on my thesis (actually the first page of the table of contents) still has a page numbering the bottom. The second problem is that the new page numbering conflicts the text of each page and I want the new numbering to be placed in the top margin like that in the screenshot
[image]

I anyone understood my problem, I ask him to help me. I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\geometry{footskip=15pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=100
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=red,
      }
   \newcommand*{\at}{@}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
   \newlength{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.05\baselineskip plus  .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
   \newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
   \let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
   \renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
    \oldthebibliography{#1}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}%
      }
   \newcommand{\comment}[1]{%
    \text{\phantom{(#1)}} \tag{#1} 
    } % to tag equations

\usepackage{tocloft}
   \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
   \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
   \setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{4em}


   % to center the part name 
   \renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
   \renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\usepackage{capt-of}

   % to appear the word "part"

\usepackage{booktabs}

   \newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}  

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 My Text  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The provided code does not produce the problem you describe. I don't see the page number at the bottom for the first page

Comment: I posted the full preamble @ChristianHupfer

Comment: Maybe declaring the document class once is enough?

Comment: I edited it @Bernard

Comment: Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: I've just checked the code, with a lipsum text, and I have a strange phenomenon: the first line of each page is *above* the header rule. I'll try to solve  this problem first. For the page number on the table of contents page, there should be several ways to set it as you want.

Comment: This phenomena is more important. I get the reason why this phenomena arose; this is because the existence of the `\fullpage` package. I deleted it but I do not know the corresponding margins using the `geometry` package. @Bernard

Comment: How does `fullpage` set the margins, exactly?

Comment: I mean the layout using the geometry package corresponding to the`fullpage`. In other words, If I want to delete `fullpage` what should I equivalently do to not change the structures of the pages ? @Bernard

Comment: I've almost finished. Will it be printed two sided or one sided? The placement of  page numbers is different in both cases.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "Will it be printed two sided or one sided? ". Besides, what equivalently should I do if I get ride of `\fullpage` command ? @Bernard

Comment: Twosided means the text will be printed on both sides of the physical  paper sheets, one sided only on one side.

Comment: One sided. Please answer my question @Bernard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is. I reorganised a little your preamble, removed `fullpage`, replacing it with the suitable parameters of `geometry`. The reason for the page number at the bottom for the table of contents page was that for this page, the `plain` page style was applied, so I redefined it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=15pt, headheight=15pt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=100
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
   \newcommand*{\at}{@}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
   \newlength{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.05\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
   \newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
   \let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
   \renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
    \oldthebibliography{#1}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}%
      }
   \newcommand{\comment}[1]{%
    \text{\phantom{(#1)}} \tag{#1}
    } % to tag equations

\usepackage{tocloft}
   \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
   \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
   \setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{4em}

   % to center the part name
   \renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
   \renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}

   \usepackage{caption}

   % to appear the word "part"

\usepackage{booktabs}

   \newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=red,
      }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
% \thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{First section}
 \lipsum
 \section{A second section}
 \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should I add this `\lipsum` command between sections ?. Another question: are the parameters of the geometry package you set equivalent in effect to "fullpage" ?

Comment: Not at all. It is just to have blind text for testing purposes. You also can remove package `lipsum` loading in the preamble. I forgot: if you don't want the header rules above the text, just use `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: You are great Bernard. But I still do not know what is meant by "the header rules above the text" ?!

Comment: It's the horizontal line between header and main text, at the top of the page.